# How can I add value of data attribute in another div?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="configurator-item">
    <ul>
        <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="122"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Inside this div I have added another div using jQuery:

Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery('li.banner-list-img').prepend(jQuery('<div class="show-price">  </div>'));
```

After I run this jQuery a div is added:

```
<div class="configurator-item">
    <ul>
        <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="122">
            <div class="show-price"> </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to get the value of data-price attribute to show inside the div(with class `show-price` with this jQuery:

```
jQuery('.banner-list-img').each(function() {
  var itemprice = jQuery(this).text();
  jQuery('.show-price').html(itemprice);
})
```

But this is not working. It should show something like this:

```
<div class="configurator-item">
    <ul>
        <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="122">
            <div class="show-price"> 122 </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do like this.

Comment: Some questions -  Where is your `.button` in html? Will there be only one `li` tag?

Comment: Yes I've noticed the mistake and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jQuery.data()` to get the data attribute and `.find()` to only update the element with show-price class which is descendant:

```js
jQuery('li.banner-list-img[data-price]').prepend(jQuery('<div class="show-price">  </div>'));

jQuery('.banner-list-img[data-price]').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.show-price').html(jQuery(this).data('price'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="configurator-item">
    <ul>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="122"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="123"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="124"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this could be improved doing the prepend with the data value all in one go:

```js
jQuery('.banner-list-img[data-price]').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).prepend(jQuery('<div class="show-price">' + jQuery(this).data('price') + '</div>'));
})
```

```css
.banner-list-img[data-price="0"] .show-price {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="configurator-item">
    <ul>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="122"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="123"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="124"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img"></li>
       <li class="banner-list-img" data-price="0"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @jeprubio. Just once question. If an li do not contain the data-price attribute it is giving an indefined error and to fix that I used this: 

jQuery('.banner-list-img').each(function() {
var price =  jQuery(this).data('price');
if(price!='0' && price!='undefined') {
jQuery(this).prepend(jQuery('<div class="show-price"> $'+ price + '</div>'));}
})

But the undefined error still shows. Could you please tell me whats the problem?

Comment: Ok, I thought these elements always had data-price. I've updated both code samples with a quick fix for this. Instead of looping `jQuery('.banner-list-img')` if you loop `jQuery('.banner-list-img[data-price]')` it will only execute in elements with banner-list-img class and data-price defined.

Comment: Today I'm learning a lot. Thank you so much. Accepted it. Just for knowledge purpose. What if we don't want to show data-attributes with price 0?

Comment: There are different ways. One way could be instead of adding the value you could use the ternary operator: `(parseInt(jQuery(this).data('price')) > 0 ? jQuery(this).data('price') : '')` when concatenating the value inside the each.

Comment: Or also hide them by css. I've updated the last sample with this.

Comment: Yeah it is possible with css. But I wanted to know the how you explained in the comment before with jQuery. Thank you mate. Hope people get benefit from the comments.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply this code

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  alert("Value: " + $(".show-price").val());
});
```

Comment: I am sorry. Looks like I mistakenly added the button and click function. Could you please take a look again at the code and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You `this` in click event is referring to button only.

So you have to do something like this

```
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
  var itemprice = jQuery('.banner-list-img').attr('data-price');
  jQuery('.show-price').html(itemprice);
})
```

Above code only works for one `li`  element. If there are multiple `li` elements you should use this code

```
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
  jQuery('.banner-list-img').each(function() {
      var itemprice = jQuery(this).attr('data-price');
      jQuery(this).children('.show-price').html(itemprice);
  })
})
```

After updating question

```
jQuery('.banner-list-img').each(function() {
     var itemprice = jQuery(this).attr('data-price');
     jQuery(this).children('.show-price').html(itemprice);
 })
```

Or more better way for your example

```
 jQuery('.banner-list-img').each(function() {
     jQuery(this).prepend('<div class="show-price">' +  jQuery(this).attr('data-price') + '</div>');
 })
```

Here we are adding HTML when prepending `div` inside `li`

Comment: I am sorry. Looks like I mistakenly added the button and click function. Could you please take a look again at the code and suggest.

Comment: @Rahul Again updated the answer Just look if that works for you. I am adding html while prepending itself. Happy to help :)